# How can I connect ST-157A-1 to my laptop?

Tags: usb, pata

I have an ancient ST-157A-1 45mb hard drive. I want to connect it to my computer and copy the data off of it. I purchased a usb-ide adapter, however it seems like the computer is completely unaware of the drive's existence - both under windows 7 and ubuntu. Any suggestions?

Comment: considering the age, sure it isn't dead?

Comment: also, is it turning up in the bios?

Comment: Best bet is to connect it to a PC with an IDE connector on the motherboard, I doubt any usb to ide adapter will be able to communicate with it, too old an architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Given the age, isn't this drive an MFM or RLL drive?  How are you hooking it up - I don't know of any USB - MFM/RLL type adapters.

Comment: http://www.impediment.com/seagate-ide-txt/st157a.txt RLL/ "AT Bus" whatever it is

Comment: Nope, it's an old IDE drive. I'm wondering whether its 5/12V power requirements mean a USB adaptor can't cope. Moab's suggestion of hooking it up internally may be a good idea.